# How can I accomplish 2 outer joins in fetchXML between same 2 entities?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to establish 2 left outer joins in fetchXML.  Can I accomplish this sql statement...

```
select
a.new_campaignid
, a.new_ContactId
, b.new_campaigncontactstatusId
from
new_ContactCampaignNN AS a 
    left outer join new_campaigncontactstatus AS b ON a.new_contactid = b.new_ContactId 
        AND a.new_campaignid = b.new_CampaignId
```

into a fetchXML statement such as this?

```
<fetch mapping='logical' distinct='true'>
  <entity name='new_contactcampaignnn'>
    <attribute name='new_campaignid' />
    <attribute name='new_contactid' />
    <filter type='and'>
      <condition attribute ='new_campaignid' operator='eq' value='72C9284B-905D-E111-9847-002655325864'/>
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='new_campaigncontactstatus' from='new_contactid' to='new_contactid' visible='true' link-type='outer' alias='new_contactcampaignnn_new_campaigncontactstatus'>
      <attribute name='new_campaigncontactstatusid' />
      <link-entity name='new_contactcampaignnn' from='new_campaignid' to='new_campaignid' visible='true' link-type='outer' alias='new_contactcampaignnn_new_campaigncontactstatus1'></link-entity>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [LINQtoCRM](http://linqtocrm.codeplex.com/) can to this and you can probably also poke around with [LinqPad](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/crmlinqpad/).

Comment: no, LINQtoCRM can't do outer join, only inner joins are supported.